# How do you return the resulting object in a function?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Good day, all! :)

For the past month, I have been working on a function to return 2 or more THREE.js materials in 1 function at 1 time. I've run into a small problem though. For some reason, I can't get this function to return the MeshBasicMaterial object AS WELL AS the MeshLambertMaterial data object. I KNOW my code is right because I've gone over it over 40 times already looking for errors.

Here's the WHOLE code:

```
/**
* A function for converting hex <-> dec w/o loss of precision.
*
* The problem is that parseInt("0x12345...") isn't precise enough to convert
* 64-bit integers correctly.
*
* Internally, this uses arrays to encode decimal digits starting with the least
* significant:
* 8 = [8]
* 16 = [6, 1]
* 1024 = [4, 2, 0, 1]
*/

// Adds two arrays for the given base (10 or 16), returning the result.
// This turns out to be the only "primitive" operation we need.

function add(x, y, base)
{

    var z = [];

    var n = Math.max(x.length, y.length);

    var carry = 0;

    var i = 0;

    while (i < n || carry)
    {

        var xi = i < x.length ? x[i] : 0;
        var yi = i < y.length ? y[i] : 0;
        var zi = carry + xi + yi;

        z.push(zi % base);
        carry = Math.floor(zi / base);
        i++;

    }

    return z;

}

// Returns a*x, where x is an array of decimal digits and a is an ordinary
// JavaScript number. base is the number base of the array x.
function multiplyByNumber(num, x, base)
{

    if (num < 0) return null;
    if (num == 0) return [];

    var result = [];
    var power = x;

    while (true)
    {

        if (num & 1)
        {

            result = add(result, power, base);

        }

        num = num >> 1;

        if (num === 0) break;

        power = add(power, power, base);

    }

    return result;

}

function parseToDigitsArray(str, base)
{

    var digits = str.split('');

    var ary = [];

    for (var i = digits.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {

        var n = parseInt(digits[i], base);
        if (isNaN(n)) return null;
        ary.push(n);

    }

    return ary;

}

function convertBase(str, fromBase, toBase)
{

    var digits = parseToDigitsArray(str, fromBase);
    if (digits === null) return null;

    var outArray = [];
    var power = [1];

        for (var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++)
        {

            // invariant: at this point, fromBase^i = power
            if (digits[i])
            {

                outArray = add(outArray, multiplyByNumber(digits[i], power, toBase), toBase);

            }

            power = multiplyByNumber(fromBase, power, toBase);

        }

    var out = '';

        for (var i = outArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {

            out += outArray[i].toString(toBase);

        }

    return out;

}

function decToHex(decStr) {
  var hex = convertBase(decStr, 10, 16);
  return hex ? '0x' + hex : null;
}

function hexToDec(hexStr) {
  if (hexStr.substring(0, 2) === '0x') hexStr = hexStr.substring(2);
  hexStr = hexStr.toLowerCase();
  return convertBase(hexStr, 16, 10);
}

function instr(str, val)
{

    if(typeof(str) === 'string')
    {

        str = str.toString(str);
        val = val.toString(val);

        in_str = str.indexOf(val);

        return in_str;

    }

    else

    {

        api_messagebox('Please use a string!');

    }

    return false;

}

function Get_RGBA(hexVal, getwhich)
{

    hexVal = hexVal || '';
    getwhich = getwhich || 0;

    var commaSeperated = 0;

    //if(typeof(hexVal) === 'string')
    //{

        // Removes the first character from the input string
        if(hexVal.length === 8) { hexVal = hexVal.substring(1, hexVal.length); }
        if(hexVal.length === 10) { hexVal = hexVal.substring(0, hexVal.length); }

        // Now let's separate the pairs by a comma
        for (var i = 0; i <= hexVal.length; i++)
        {

            // Iterate through each char of hexVal

            // Copy each char of hexVal to commaSeperated
            commaSeperated += hexVal.charAt(i);

            // After each pair of characters add a comma, unless this
            // is the last char
            commaSeperated += (i % 2 == 1 && i != (hexVal.length - 1)) ? ',' : '';

        }

        // Lets now remove the 0x
        if(instr(commaSeperated, '0x'))
        {

            commaSeperated = commaSeperated.substr(4);

        }

        if(instr(commaSeperated, ','))
        {

            // Lets now remove all "," 's
            commaSeperated = commaSeperated.replace(/,/g, '');

            if( getwhich < 0 ) { getwhich = 0; }
            if( getwhich > 5 ) { getwhich = 5; }

            alpha   = [];
              red   = [];
            green   = [];
             blue   = [];
           allcol   = [];
           sixcol   = [];

           alpha[0] = commaSeperated[0]+commaSeperated[1];
             red[0] = commaSeperated[2]+commaSeperated[3];
           green[0] = commaSeperated[4]+commaSeperated[5];
            blue[0] = commaSeperated[6]+commaSeperated[7];
          allcol[0] =    alpha[0]+red[0]+green[0]+blue[0];
          sixcol[0] =             red[0]+green[0]+blue[0];

            if( getwhich === 0 ) { fi_string =  alpha[0]; }

            if( getwhich === 1 ) { fi_string =    red[0]; }
            if( getwhich === 2 ) { fi_string =  green[0]; }
            if( getwhich === 3 ) { fi_string =   blue[0]; }
            if( getwhich === 4 ) { fi_string = allcol[0]; }
            if( getwhich === 5 ) { fi_string = sixcol[0]; }

            if( getwhich === 4 && fi_string.length != 10 || fi_string.length != 9 ) { getwhich = 5; }
            if( getwhich === 5 && fi_string.length !=  8 || fi_string.length != 7 ) { getwhich = 4; }

            // Split the commaSeperated string by commas and return the array
            return fi_string.toString();

        }

    //}

}

function isArray(myArray)
{

    return myArray.constructor.toString();
    //myArray.constructor.toString().indexOf("Array") > -1;

}

//EntityMaterial(0, 0, 0xFF44CFFC, 1, 0xFF000000, 4, 4, 0, 1.0, 0.8, "LambertBasicMaterial", 1)
function EntityMaterial(ptex, side, color, wire, wirecolor, col_type, col_wire_type, shading, transparent, opacity, mat_type, overdraw)
{

    ptex = ptex || 0;

    side = side || 0;

    color = color || 0xFF006400;

    wire = wire || 0;

    wirecolor = wirecolor || 0xFF006400;

    col_type = col_type || 4;

    col_wire_type = col_wire_type || 4;

    shading = shading || false;

    transparent = transparent || 0.0;

    opacity = opacity || 1.0;

    mat_type = mat_type || "BasicMaterial";

    overdraw = overdraw || true;

    color = decToHex(color.toString());
    wirecolor = decToHex(wirecolor.toString());

    var gRGBA1 = Get_RGBA(color, col_type);
    var gRGBA2 = Get_RGBA(wirecolor, col_wire_type);

    var mat = 0;

    if(mat_type === 'BasicMaterial')
    {

        this.materials = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial
        (

            {

                color: parseInt(gRGBA1, 16)

            }

        )

    }

    else if(mat_type === 'LambertMaterial')

    {

        this.materials = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial
        (

            {

                color: parseInt(gRGBA2, 16), 
                opacity: opacity, 
                wireframe: wire, 
                transparent: transparent

            }

        )

    }

    else if(mat_type === 'LambertBasicMaterial')

    {

        //new empty array.. could also be written as this.materials = new Array();
        this.materials = [];

        var mats = this.materials;

            var basicMat       =     new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {   color: parseInt(gRGBA1, 16) } );
            var lambertMat     =   new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {   color: parseInt(gRGBA2, 16), opacity: opacity, wireframe: wire, transparent: transparent } );

            mats.push(basicMat);
            mats.push(lambertMat);

            api_messagebox(mats);

        return mats;

    }

}
```

Thank you so much!

Sincerely,

~Mythros

Comment: It looks like you have an unnecessary comma at "color: parseInt(gRGBA1, 16)," in the first object within your first if statement.

Comment: You're calling "EntityMaterial" as a plain function but in the function you apparently expect `this` to be some object reference. You're probably not in "strict" mode, so `this` will be a reference to `window`.

Comment: Hey guys. thanks for the quick reply and the help! :) I edited the code above to reflect the new change, but it still is not returning both Materials. :(

Comment: So what does it return?

Comment: It somehow only returns

var basicMat       =     new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {   color: parseInt(gRGBA1, 16) } ); But not

var basicMat       =     new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {   color: parseInt(gRGBA1, 16) } ); AND        var lambertMat     =   new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {   color: parseInt(gRGBA2, 16), opacity: opacity, wireframe: wire, transparent: transparent } ); It returns them like this: object [Object], object [Object]

Comment: And are you sure it's executing the last `else if` block? If you gave us the whole function and the line which calls it we could help more.

Comment: Take `this.materials` and `var mats` declarations outside of the if/else statements and use it as an array *properly*

Comment: The logic you have is to either have materials set as an array or a material. Doesn't make sense.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get your question, do you want to return multiple materials from this function which you have written ? which does some business and finds out which two to return, please confirm, If so then why don't you return this.material itself and use it

Comment: @LcLk: Yes, I'm sure. I will edit my post above to show the whole function. aravind.udayashankara: I want to return multiple materials from the function I have written, correct.

Comment: Ok, I edited the above with the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Right, I finally got around to trying it out and it all runs well for me.
To make sure we don't have any differences in environments take a look at the fiddle I made and let me know if it works for you as expected or if there's any other problems you need help with:

[JSFiddle of original code](http://jsfiddle.net/LcLk/ts01kh9t/2/)

Small changes:
commented out the

```
api_messagebox(mats)
```

as it's undefined.
added lots of log statements so check out the web console.

---

### Edit

I fixed the color problem by using THree.js' Color object as follows:

```
    var color = new THREE.Color("rgb(0,0,255)");
```

But you may be doing this somewhere as the `GET_RGBA` function you are calling seems to be missing from the code you gave me.

As to making it wiremesh, I checked the Lambert object and it definitely had `wiremesh = 1` set.

Make sure that the `wire` var you're passing is actually set to true, I set it explicitly in this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ts01kh9t/5/)

Comment: Hi, LcLk, sorry for the long awaited reply. I am just now getting to this. It works ok, but for some reason, the 3D Object is STILL not wireframe AND blue... :/ Just blue...

Comment: Hi, LcLk! :) This is CLOSE. It's at least showing SOME wireframe after I realized that when "pushing", the 2 mats must be called in the EXACT same order as it is in the original code, otherwise, the basic material will overlap the lambert material. Anyway, for some reason this is still showing only white colored black wireframed mesh. It should be blue... I have uploaded a new pastebin of the function, here: http://pastebin.com/Tudhx2E4 Thank you! :)

Comment: Basically, the EntityMaterial() function when used, should make the object look like this (color, wireframe and all). Not necessarily that same COLOR, but if it works with color & wireframe, then problem solved. http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_extrude_splines.html Thank you SO kindly for your help! :)

Comment: @Mythros, color seems to be related to your get_RGBA function, if you don't give that code I can't help. Just use the color function I gave in the answer.

Comment: I DID give you the code. look above. It is: "function Get_RGBA(hexVal, getwhich)
{" Also, I tried your color code thing, and it still was white colored with a black wireframe. Thank you! :)

Comment: Right, my bad there, I was using the original code in my fiddle all along, updated now. I popped your blue color into [this example](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/three/html5-canvas-three-js-lambert-material/) and it turned blue. I can't help you any further but good luck.